# Laravel - Can't create Accessor for field named 'edge_50mm'

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, accessor

I have a `Product` model with field '`edge_50mm`'.
The trouble is when I create `Accessor` for that field named `getEdge50mmAttribute`, it doesn't work. I think it's because of the number 50 in the field name.
I also tried with capital M like `getEdge50MmAttribute`, but with no success.
Accessors for other fields that have no numbers in their names work.

I would appreciate any help or suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Try to `dd()` a single model and find the attribute name set by laravel like `dd(Product::first());`

Comment: It would probably help if you posted some code, it may be a simple mistake, but there is really know way to know without an idea of what you have so far.

Comment: getEdge50mmAttribute should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't reproducible.  Laravel uses their studly case helper to convert the name of the property and check for a mutator:

```
> Str::studly('edge_50mm'); 
"Edge50mm"
```

So, either edge_50mm and edge50mm will work the same.

```
function getEdge50mmAttribute() {
    return 'Hello World';
}
```

Example:

```
> $model->edge50mm
"Hello World"
> $model->edge_50mm
"Hello World"
```